# Disabling Ambient framework and Content Preview gives error

Tags: content-manager, ambient-data-framework

I am trying to disbale the ambient framwework and tridion content preview modules by removing below modules

```
<add name="Tridion.ContentDelivery.AmbientData.HttpModule"
    type="Tridion.ContentDelivery.AmbientData.HttpModule" preCondition="managedHandler" />
<add name="PreviewContentModule"
    type="Tridion.ContentDelivery.Preview.Web.PreviewContentModule" />
```

However when eevr I am doing this I am getting below error when my webpage is trying to make a broker query

> Java.Lang.ClassNotFoundException: com.tridion.broker.querying.Query

However if a put the above modules back i am able to execute broker query sucessfully

I am using Tridion 2011 SP1 content delivery.

Comment: <add name="Tridion.ContentDelivery.AmbientData.HttpModule" type="Tridion.ContentDelivery.AmbientData.HttpModule" preCondition="managedHandler" />            
     <add name="PreviewContentModule" type="Tridion.ContentDelivery.Preview.Web.PreviewContentModule" />

Comment: why do you want to disable just the ambient framework and preview module? Any specific reason? Also, are you trying to configure this in your web app?

Comment: well, don't need it in Live site

Comment: have you disabled it completely from storage config, removed cd_ambient config etc?

Comment: yes, have disbaled it completely, only weird thing is if only I enable Tridion.ContentDelivery.AmbientData.HttpModule in web.config, then only it works otherwise no broker query is being fired and giving class not found exception